Can I use the existing breaker from hot tub for office shed
I have an old hot tub that is leaking and I can’t fix. I’m thinking of getting rid of it and replacing the space with an office shed for remote work. The main panel already has a breaker that was supplying power to the hot tub. I see a 60A double pole and a 20A breaker. Would this be enough to power the new shed? I’m thinking of having a mini split to heat and cool the space along with a couple of outlets for computer, monitors, maybe a TV, and indoor lighting.

The 60 amp will be more than enough.  You will want a sub panel fed from the 60, to power that stuff, since most of it will only need 15 or 20 amp circuit/s.  The sub panel must be equal or larger than 60 amps.

Check the number and coloring of the insulation of the wires feeding the spa panel. Is there a white or gray wire that is (or could be) used for the neutral connection? What gauge is that wire?

does the 60A circuit have a neutral?

Depending on the size of the shed a Minisplit may be too big and you will need to go to a wall AC unit.  Also the mini-Split will require a 30 amp breaker minimum. The wall AC only a 20 possibly only a 15
